# NOS vintage hub vs modern hub

Tags: hub, vintage, bearings

I have an early 80s Schwinn Prelude. I need to replace the rear wheel.

The question at hand is should I spend $300 on a pair of NOS (new old stock) Superbe Pro hubs, which have the original 126 mm spacing it came with, or should I respace the rear dropouts to accommodate a modern spacing (130 mm). I like my current gear ratio as well as the classic downtube shifters. I could be convinced to modernize to bar shifters and 8-10 speed cassette but I'd like to see what my options are.

The fundamental question is as follows: is a vintage high end component set better than a mid range modern set (eg. Tiagra)? Specifically the hubs and bearings?

Comment: Bearings is one area where high-end is always high-end. The other advantages of going modern may outweigh this though.

Comment: Do you value period correct restoration or are you building just a rideable bike?

Comment: Why do you need new hubs in the first place? If the old ones are really broken I’d go for a modern 130mm freehub. Freewheels are prone to bent axles. Shimano cup&cone hub bearings are solid and will last many kilometers when properly adjusted and re-greased from time to time.

Comment: Do you need to replace the wheel because of the rim or because of the hub? If the rim is has gone bad you could build a new wheel with a new rim (and spokes) and keep the hub. You may just want to refurbish the hub with fresh bearings and grease.

Comment: Joe K what would be the advantages and disadvantages you're referring to? No period accuracy isn't a big deal. I'd rather have a new hub that works fantastically than a vintage one that's just pretty good. Long story short the wheel got bent badly, took it to an LBS and the idiot there threw the whole thing away instead of building a new wheel around the hub. The wheel he replaced it with is complete garbage that you could find on bike from Target. I've probably spent more money repairing it then it cost in the first place. So yes I need a whole new wheel, hub included.

Comment: Is it 27" but with no barriers to making it 700 except also needing to buy a tire, i.e. brake reach has the 4mm to give to make it 700?

Comment: Going NOS or used isn't the only choice other than reinventing the bike. 126mm freewheel repair wheels of acceptable quality for a ridden bike are available new in both 700 and 27". For example, one of the larger US wholesalers has these: https://www.jbi.bike/site/product_details.php?part_number=72385 . I've put them on a number of 80s road bikes that needed repair more than reinvention/refurb. If the original wheel lasted a decade or four, i.e. the use case is not one where the freewheel-ness is a problem due to bent axles, they're pretty good. The QR they come with is trash.

Comment: Woah I've never heard of that website but that changes the game a bit. Anyone know the difference between the Origin8 RD 2100, Wheel Master AQ 1000 and Wheel Master AQ 2000? Quick price check shows Origin8 - $31, WM AQ 1000 - $25, WM AQ 2000 - $21. For ten dollars difference I'd take the best of the three. Any input would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Ben, the best hubs with cup and cone bearings have hardened races and better precision. They feel better and last longer.  The superbe pro was a high-end hub so should fit this discription. It's one reason why XT and Ultegra hubs are more expensive than Deore and Tiagra

Comment: The RD 2100 is a decent quality cartridge freewheel hub. It's a rebadged Quando and is a straightforward shouldered axle design. I have a pretty decent opinion of it as freewheel hubs go and I'm a snob.

Answer (score 3):

If period correctness is not an issue, a modern cassette hub is the better choice. The problem with old freewheel design is that it puts the drive side bearings in the center of the axle where the weight of the rider can bend or break the axle. Modern hubs either put the bearings to the end of the axle or use an oversize axle that can take the load. Other benefits of modern hubs are that because the freewheel mechanism is part of the hub, you don't have to pay for new one when the cogs are worn out, cassettes are easy to replace because they don't tighten themselves when riding and finally, there are lots of affordable decent quality cassettes to choose from.